# How do I locate the function that is stealing DOM focus?

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments, dom-events, focus

I'm trying to debug the integration between my app and [Stripe's Elements component library](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js). Everything works fine in sandbox mode, but we ran into a problem on production in the [3D Secure authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure) process. This involves loading an iframe, into our app, that contains a form from the credit card's issuer (usually via a technology partner, like [Arcot](https://docs.arcot.com/)).

The form loads correctly and its buttons are working as expected, but the  element (for a SMS one time code) is not behaving. Every time I click on the input, something is immediately pushing the focus back to the  element of the iframe. This makes it impossible to type anything in, since by the time I touch a key, the input is not in focus. *For reference, it is possible to change the input's value using `document.getElementById('enterPIN').value = '123456';`*

I'm not sure if my app is triggering `focus()` calls (I don't think so) or if it is some part of the iframe code or even Stripe's. **Is there a good way to monitor DOM events and do a stack trace  for the trigger of each one?**

Answer (score 4):

I found this helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/accessibility/focus

Adding `document.activeElement` as a live expression in the chromium console allows you to watch in real time which element is focused.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried two tactics. Neither gave an obvious answer, but they did point my search in the right direction.

1. I opened the *Event Listeners* panel (in the *Elements* tab of my  browser's developer tools) and removed everything I could find, but it seems that this doesn't actually change the behavior of the page- focus kept being stolen away. Luckily, I also noticed some listeners that were defined by the Material UI library.
2. I used `monitorEvents()` to get a few more details, but the src & target values were not much help and `event.relatedTarget` was always null.

In the end, I found [this discussion](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15694#issuecomment-514812038) and realized that my MUI Dialog component was stealing focus whenever I clicked on the iframe triggered by its content. This was easily fixed by adding the `disableEnforceFocus` attribute.